# Mysterious jumping issue with every gaming mouse I buy. Am I cursed?

Tags: windows, mouse

3 years ago, I purchased a gaming mouse (Razer Deathadder) to use on Windows 10, but it had a weird issue where it would jump randomly every few seconds. Nobody understood what I was talking about, so, after hours trying to find a solution to no avail, I assumed it was faulty hardware, sent it back and stayed with my normal mouse. 1 year later, I purchased another gaming mouse, but it had the same issue, so I assumed it was something on Windows and sent it back. 3 years later, I now purchased another gaming mouse (Logitech Pro) to use on a Windows 11, Razer Blade 14" notebook. Despite being a completely different machine, with a completely different mouse and a OS (fresh install), **I'm having the same issue** (!?)

[This time, I recorded a video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrvXUC8g8QU)

I've tried everything:

- Disabled "enhance pointer precision" on mouse settings
- Disabled the trackpad to make sure I wasn't touching it
- Disabled every other mouse driver on Device Settings
- Closed all applications that could relate (Parsec, AutoHotkey, Discord...)
- Disabled my custom keyboard layout
- Reinstalled the mouse drivers (but Windows said it is already up-to-date)
- Reinstalled LG Hub
- Prayed

Weirdly enough, my LG Hub screen is different on Windows vs Mac. On Windows, it doesn't allow me to configure the mouse. [Windows screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSWn0.jpg) [Mac screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnJAK.jpg)

At this point, I believe I'm cursed to never have a gaming mouse. This is my last hope.

Comment: So did you enable software control mode or more specifically disable the on-board memory mode?

Comment: @Ramhound I wish I could answer but I don't know what you mean. How do I do that?

Comment: Click the “Enable” button in your screenshot.

Comment: @Ramhound ah, I see. I tried both ways, with and without on-board memory. Same issue.

Comment: I had a Similar Problem , where the Issue was with the Mouse PAD ! There was a "bump" in the middle , which made the Pointer move erratically. When avoiding that Area , no more jumps ! In your Case , I think that changing the PAD or the table or at least the Position will help !